What is the proper MethodType for invocation of a default constructor?
Suggest the code below. To me, it looks fine: I do obtain a MethodType, which takes no parameters as input, and produces an instance of A. The default constructor of a matches
that description, in my opinion, so I would expect that findConstructor(mt) works. However, I get an Exception. Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?
Thanks,
Jochen
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such constructor: com.github.jochenw.afw.core.rflct.RflctDemo$A.<init>()A/newInvokeSpecial
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:974)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1117)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:3649)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findConstructor(MethodHandles.java:2750)
    at com.github.jochenw.afw.core.rflct.RflctDemo.main(RflctDemo.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.github.jochenw.afw.core.rflct.RflctDemo$A com.github.jochenw.afw.core.rflct.RflctDemo$A.<init>()'
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:1085)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1114)
    ... 3 more

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup;

public class RflctDemo {
    /** Instance class, that has a no-args constructor.
     */
    public static class A {
        private boolean valid;
        /** Creates a new instance with {@link #isValid() valid} == false.
         */
        public A() { this(false); }
        A(boolean pValid) { valid = pValid; }
        boolean isValid() { return valid; }
        void setValid(boolean pValid) { valid = pValid; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] pArgs) throws Throwable {
        final Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(A.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
        final MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(A.class /* No parameters */);
        final MethodHandle mh = lookup.findConstructor(A.class, mt);
        final A a = (A) mh.invoke(/* No üarameters */);
    }
}


it is not the constructor that returns ("produces") the new instance, it is the new command (the name constructor is not the exact description of what it does)

Read the documentation on findConstructor, which explicitly says:

The requested type must have a return type of void. (This is consistent with the JVM's treatment of constructor type descriptors.)


If I get this right, you are suggesting to replace the first argument in the methodType() invocation. Okay, but with what? I tried Void.TYPE, and Void.class, but neither works.

void.class is what I'd expect to work.

void.class and Void.TYPE should equally work. In contrast to Void.class
